# How to Reset Your Mac Password on Apple - OS X Mavericks

Tags: macos

i forgot my password and i am the only user on my mac how can i reset it ?
i followed this example and may others  i was able to find on the internet  without succes

```
http://osxdaily.com/2010/08/10/forgot-mac-password-how-to-reset-mac-password/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try this on the mac support page

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1274

or this

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S8eAU-Qyfec

1.first shutdown your mac and press `CMD+R` on startup until you see the apple logo

2.then you will see a window asking for the language press enter and go to utilities

3.then select the terminal

4.type in "resetpassword"

5.select system amdin and enter your new password and that s all

Comment: this is not an answer. Try to post in comment.